# PHP Combine Array and Sorting It

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new in PHP array, and I have a multidimensional array like this: `$person['id'] = $value;`
My sample data is like this:

```
$person[1]=110
$person[2]=200
$person[3]=300
$person[4]=100
$person[5]=220
```

Right now, I want to sort it by its value, so my array should be like these:

```
$person[3]=300
$person[5]=220
$person[2]=200
$person[1]=110
$person[4]=100
```

After this, I want to print it numbers of sorting... So my result would be like these:

```
$person[3]=1
$person[5]=2
$person[2]=3
$person[1]=4
$person[4]=5
```

Here's my full code:

```
$person = array();
$person[1]=110;
$person[2]=200;
$person[3]=300;
$person[4]=100;
$person[5]=220;

rsort($person);
foreach($person as $x => $x_value) {
   echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
   echo "<br>";
}
```

And that's it, I'm stuck to change the value to what I want. Anyone know how to create a code that I wanted?

Comment: have a look at **asort()** http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: try `asort` inplace of `rsort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [arsort](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.arsort.php): Sorts an array in reverse order and maintain index association

```
<?PHP
$person = array();
$person[1]=110;
$person[2]=200;
$person[3]=300;
$person[4]=100;
$person[5]=220;

arsort($person);
$i=0;
foreach($person as &$p){
    $p=++$i;
}

var_dump($person);
```

so your output will be:

```
array(5) {
  [3]=>
  int(1)
  [5]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  &int(5)
}
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly.. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

use **`asort()`** method of php for sorting array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

```
<?php
$person = array();
$person[1]=110;
$person[2]=200;
$person[3]=300;
$person[4]=100;
$person[5]=220;
asort($person);
foreach($person as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `asort` inplace of `rsort`

```
<?php
$person = array();
$person[1]=110;
$person[2]=200;
$person[3]=300;
$person[4]=100;
$person[5]=220;

asort($person);
foreach($person as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```